# Passing string to function and returning a structure

Tags: c, string, structure

I am trying to achieve the simple objective of passing a string to a function and returning a structure containing data about that string. I have written this, but when I try to compile it I get a runtime error and I can't understand why. I thank you kindly for having a look.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

struct stringStats
{
    int length;
    int uppercase;
    int lowercase;
    int digits;
    int nonAlphaNum;
};

struct stringStats stringReader (char anyString[])
{
    int i;
    struct stringStats returned = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    returned.length = strlen(anyString);

    for (i = 0; anyString[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (isupper(anyString[i]))
            ++returned.uppercase;
        if (islower(anyString[i]))
            ++returned.lowercase;
        if (isdigit(anyString[i]))
            ++returned.digits;
        if (isalnum(anyString[i]) == 0)
            ++returned.nonAlphaNum;
    }
    return returned;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct stringStats stored;
    char passedString[] = "Th1s string's g0t it all!";
    stored = stringReader(passedString);
    printf ("%i\n%i\n%i\n%i\n%i\n", stored.length, stored.uppercase, stored.lowercase,
                                    stored.digits, stored.nonAlphaNum);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Ganesh i was wrong. he is returning the value of the struct. thats ok.

Comment: @Koushik.. thanks .. deleted my comment also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
char passedString = "Th1s string's g0t it all!";
```

not sure how this compiled (recommend compiling at highest warning level and treat warnings as error):

```
$ gcc -O2 -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -pedantic main.c -o main -pthread
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:38:25: error: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror]
main.c:39:5: error: passing argument 1 of ‘stringReader’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
main.c:14:20: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

The type should be `char[]`:

```
char passedString[] = "Th1s string's g0t it all!";
```

Note the return type is legal as a copy of the local variable is being returned (by value), not the address of the local variable. Just to warn that copying a `struct` is dangerous if the `struct` contains pointer members as now two `struct`s have members pointing to the same address (a potential source of dangling pointers).

The local `struct` does need initialized though, as it is not currently:

```
struct stringStats returned = {0}; /* All members initialized to zero. */
```

The `for` loop condition is incorrect and will result in the body of the loop never being executed (the first evaluation is `0 != '\0'` which will be false). Change to:

```
for (i = 0; anyString[i]; ++i)
{
}
```

Comment: the for loop seems to be incorrect in his code. shed some light on that.

Comment: Yes, now that it compiles. It only returns the value for string length. The rest are zeroed out.

Comment: @RossCournoyer, fix the `for` loop terminating condition as shown in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Several problems here.

1. In main() you have `char passedString = "Th1s string's g0t it all!";` - char is to store a single character, so this should be `char *passedString = "Th1s string's g0t it all!";`
2. You are not initialising the members of `returned` before incrementing them.
3. Your termination condition on your for loop is checking the value of `i` itself, whereas you actually want to check the value of `anyString[i]` to terminate on a null character.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the value of a local structure to a calling object. From my experience, it is safer to just pass the reference, and perform the operation inside.

Take a look at this::

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

struct stringStats
{
    int length;
    int uppercase;
    int lowercase;
    int digits;
    int nonAlphaNum;
};

int stringReader (char anyString[], struct stringStats *returned)
{
    int i;
    returned->digits=0;
    returned->length=0;
    returned->lowercase=0;
    returned->nonAlphaNum=0;
    returned->uppercase=0;

    returned->length = strlen(anyString);

    for (i = 0; anyString[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (isupper(anyString[i]))
            ++returned->uppercase;
        if (islower(anyString[i]))
            ++returned->lowercase;
        if (isdigit(anyString[i]))
            ++returned->digits;
        if (isalnum(anyString[i]) == 0)
            ++returned->nonAlphaNum;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct stringStats stored;
    char passedString[] = "Th1s string's g0t it all!";
    stringReader(passedString,&stored);
    printf ("%i\n%i\n%i\n%i\n%i\n", stored.length, stored.uppercase, stored.lowercase,
                                    stored.digits, stored.nonAlphaNum);

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles and runs perfectly on my end. Hope this helps!